# Resize the float Div width to 100% after floating

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to do something like this, when left dive hide the right div float left but i need with the right div should resize and fill the blank space of left dive after hide or show.

```
<div class="main">
<!--heqd start-->
<div class="head">
    <div class="head_l">
    <!--logo -->
    <img src="master3_img/logo_m.png" alt="logo" />
    </div>

    <div class="head_r"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<!--head end-->

<!--body part start-->
<div class="body">
<!--body left-->
<div class="body_l">
<div id="slide"></div>
<div id="clicky" class="s_r">Click me</div>
```

```
<!--body right-->
<div class="body_r"></div>
<!--body right end-->

</div>
<!--body part end-->
```

```
    $(function(){ 

$("#clicky").click(function(){
    if($("#slide").is(':visible'))
  {
    $("#slide").animate({ width: 'hide' }); 
  }
  else
  {
    $("#slide").animate({ width: 'show' }); 

  }
});



});
```

[My working Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/onlypriyaranjan/5x5jxwjb/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Hope this will solve your problem.

Change `<div class="body_r"></div>` to  `<div id="body_r"></div>`.

```
$(function(){ 

  $("#clicky").click(function(){
    if($("#slide").is(':visible'))
      {
        $("#slide").animate({ width: 'hide' }); 
      }
    else
      {
        $("#slide").animate({ width: 'show' }); 
        $("#body_r").width('100%');       
      }
 });   
});
```